# Doctrine + Oracle = maximum open cursors exceeded (ORA-01000)

Tags: php, oracle, symfony1, doctrine

I'm currently using Doctrine on an Oracle DB, using the `Doctrine_Adapter_Oracle`.

My application deals with some batch treatment, involving querying and inserting/hydrating a lot of objects (~700+).

When doing that, I get an error from Oracle :

```
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded 

ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.DOCUMENT_AI_PK' : INSERT INTO (...)
```

My maximum cursors allowed by Oracle is 300, which IMO, is **a lot**. So am I missing something, or is there something wrong with Doctrine ?

After some googling, I found this [Entry on the Doctrine bug tracker: "Oracle don't close cursor"](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-509). I tried the suggested patch, and it seems to work. However, I'm really reluctant to use it, as it seems to be discouraged by Jonathan Wage (Doctrine's lead).

I'm pretty stuck on this one, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Was this fixed? The bug link is now broken. I'm running into the same problem and I wonder if it's the doctrine version?

Comment: @Murphpdx it's been a while :x I'm not sure it has been fixed. Your best bet is to open a ticket on the github repo, with a reproductible case, and ask the community for help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much question there's something wrong with Doctrine. You have two choices when faced with this error:

1. Close cursors ASAP
2. Increase OPEN_CURSORS

The discussion in the link provided seems to center around what is the right way to fix it within Doctrine.

Comment: Basically you're telling me to increase the allowed number of cursor, or to fix Doctrine. I can't just "close cursors ASAP", as they're fully managed by Doctrine.

Comment: I'm looking for some pointers on how to fix Doctrie, or advices on how good is the fix. (sorry, allowed edit time was expired)

Comment: Except you can, with the patch, no? Isn't that what the link you posted was saying? You yourself said it solved the cursor issue for you. Something is broken. Your choices as I see are what I've listed. I guess if that warrants a downvote, so be it.

Comment: Yup, the patch **seems** to fix the problem, but in fact it skips some Doctrine internal logic, mainly some event throwing before and after execution of the requests. I'm afraid that using the patch I'd exchange an unexpected behavior for another. I'm aware of these choices, I'm looking for advices/deus ex machina I guess ^^.

Comment: Then IMO you have one other option: find a tool that's not broken. The answer I gave was a general solution to the problem you describe.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not saying your answer is wrong, just not the one I was looking for. I didn't mean to upset you =).

Comment: It's really not a matter of my being upset. The one question you actually asked here is if there was something wrong with Doctrine. IMO, the answer is yes. In the short term, perhaps you can up the number of open cursors allowed, but longer term someone needs to fix this bug in Doctrine. This is one of the risks of using abstraction layers - you lose control over situations like this one. Sorry I can't pull a rabbit out of the hat for you ;-)

Comment: Hehehe, a rabbit out of a hat is a good image of what I'm looking for!